# Addon BLAM - Lines doesn't line up

Tags: add-on, camera, fspy, blam

I have a strange problem with addon called BLAM. I watched a lot of tutorials about using BLAM, but I can't figure out what is the problem. It isn't first time when I'm trying to recreate a real scene into Blender and lines just doesn't line up.

Here are some screenshots from Blender.

[image: blam]
Of course I'm trying to best match perspective lines to image. In this case it's not actually that bad, but still it makes harder to fully recreate our scene without dimentions.
[image: camera and viewport]

Am I doing something wrong ?

Sorry for English, Matt